# Use Highcharts in php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have a php website with mysql database. I want to use highcharts in customer dashboard for every different user which exist in database. When customer login highcharts fetch the data from db table.

My SQL information:
Table Name is : orders
Row name: orderType
using two values in orderType Order another is Vector
Date Row name : oDate

My database query which i am doing :

```
<?php $orders = ""; $sql = "select count(*) as Orders,MONTH(oDate) as Month from orders where userID='" . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "' AND (orderType = 'Order')AND EXTRACT(YEAR from oDate)=" . $year . " group by(MONTH(oDate))"; $result = $conn->query($sql); ?>
```

I made code but its not working I have something is wrong in php its not fetching the data for login user.

One table and one row but i want two result its depend orderType Value in database.

```
<?php

$year = date("Y");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $year = $_POST['year'];

}
?>
<style type="text/css">
    #container2{
        color: red;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 21px;
        background: black;
    }
    ${demo.css}
</style>
<script src="Highcharts-4.0.4/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-4.0.4/js/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-4.0.4/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-4.0.4/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="customer.php" style="margin:0px; background-color:black;">
    <select name="year" required style="margin-top:10px; background-color:black; color:white;">
        <?php for ($i = date("Y"); $i >= date("Y") - 100; $i--) { ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $i ?>' <?php if ($year == $i) echo "selected" ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Select</button>
</form>
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<div id="container2" style="width:100%; height:400px;">
    NO ORDER
</div>




<?php
$orders = "";
$sql = "select count(*) as Orders,MONTH(oDate) as Month from orders  where userID='" . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "' AND (orderType = 'Order')AND EXTRACT(YEAR from oDate)=" . $year . "  group by(MONTH(oDate))";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var orderData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var vectorData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            orderData[<?php echo $row["Month"] ?> - 1] =<?php echo $row["Orders"] ?>;
        <?php
    }
}
$sql = "select count(*) as Vectors,MONTH(oDate) as Month from orders  where userID='" . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "' AND (orderType = 'Vector')AND EXTRACT(YEAR from oDate)=" . $year . "  group by(MONTH(oDate))";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            vectorData[<?php echo $row["Month"] ?> - 1] =<?php echo $row["Vectors"] ?>;

        <?php
    }
}
?>
//    alert(orderData);
//    alert(vectorData);
    $(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#d01422', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
        });
        $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Customer Dashboard'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'number of orders/vectors'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    name: 'Orders',
                    data: orderData

                }, {
                    name: 'Vectors',
                    data: vectorData

                }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is it correct code below:
<?php
$orders = "";
$sql = "select count(*) as Orders,MONTH(oDate) as Month from orders  where userID='" . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "' AND (orderType = 'Order')AND EXTRACT(YEAR from oDate)=" . $year . "  group by(MONTH(oDate))";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Reading data from the database to output it to the arrays for HighCharts? Please remove the unneccessary parts from your code

Comment: Can you add orderData and vectorData arrays using console log

Comment: my php query is correct or i am using wrong below code for take the output in graph ?

<?php $orders = ""; $sql = "select count(*) as Orders,MONTH(oDate) as Month from orders where userID='" . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "' AND (orderType = 'Order')AND EXTRACT(YEAR from oDate)=" . $year . " group by(MONTH(oDate))"; $result = $conn->query($sql); ?>

Comment: Does the chart display without the data? Are there any errors in the console? Also please provide the information requested by @Deep3015.